# Turing machines that return to the same configuration

Tags: turing-machines

Last year I took a course on Theory of Computation. One of the questions made a reference to a Turing machine as a "Potato" (the course was root vegetable themed). A Turing machine is a Potato if on any input it either a) halts or b) reaches a configuration that it has already been in. I'm currently a TA for this course now, and none of the former TAs or even the professor know that this type of Turing machine is actually called, or even if there is such a name for one. Can anyone cite any papers that used this type of Turing machine and know what it is called outside the context of this course.

Comment: I have never heard such name "Potato", but it looks like [Linear Bounded Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton).

Comment: My guess would be that it was just a made-up name for a made-up concept. Maybe it's a concept that's mentioned in the literature and whoever thought about it gave it a more scientific-sounding name, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @fade2black Any class of TMs with any kind of bound on the tape would be a "potato" -- not just LBAs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Agree. We could then give it this definition.

Comment: If you're in the case (b), there is a notation of periodic configurations so I wouldn't be surprised if someone were to refer to such machines as "periodic TMs".